# Why is this file reading code generating exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, iostream

I have a function (`addShape`) to read ints from a file according to the `id` it gets. It gets the `id` and the stream `is` as parameters. for some reason I get thrown with `std::ios_base::failure` after reading the last line.

```
while (is >> id)
    addShape(id, is, false);
```

I thought that this is the safest way to read from a file.

This is how I initialize the stream:

```
fstream is;
int id = 0;
string filename;
char answer = NULL;

// set exceptions
is.exceptions(fstream::failbit | fstream::badbit);

try { is.open(filename); }

catch (ifstream::failure e)
{
    clrscr();
    cout << "There was an error opening " << filename << endl;
    waitForEscape();
    is.close();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're initializing the stream `is` and the code for `addShape`? You may have enabled exceptions on the stream object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're creating the stream, notice that you're turning on exceptions whenever `failbit` is set:

```
// set exceptions
is.exceptions(fstream::failbit | fstream::badbit);
```

This means that any time a stream operation sets `failbit`, the stream will throw an exception.

Now, look at this code:

```
while (is >> id)
    addShape(id, is, false);
```

At some point the read `is >> id` will fail, either because you run out of data or because the data is malformed. When this happens with exceptions turned off, this will fail by setting `failbit` and having `is >> id` evaluate to `false`, stopping the loop. However, with exceptions turned on, when `failbit` is set in this case, it will throw an exception.

Depending on what you want to do, you can either

- Not set exceptions for `failbit`, which will cause the loop to stop running when an error occurs, or
- Set up an explicit exception handler around the `while` loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to have an exception if the file couldn't be opened, is it possible to turn the exception off after the file is opened?

Comment: @Quaker- Yes, that should be possible by calling `is.exceptions(0)`. That said, if you just want to throw an exception if a single operation fails, you might consider instead leaving exceptions off and then manually checking for a failure yourself and throwing an exception if something goes wrong. That seems like a more elegant solution.